# Compare 2 Strings with the same words but different position

Tags: string

```
 String a = "yes,weak,normal";
 String b = "normal,weak,yes";
```

i need to compare these string and return true

Comment: You can convert them to array and check for all of the elements of that String array. That would be really very helpfull. Because this also needs to be splitted and then checked, creating one more step for you to cover. Too bad.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include what you've tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is `write code for me, here are a few vague requirements`

Answer (score 1):

You could split string `a` on ",".
then loop over each word in that array and use `IndexOf` to compare it to string `b`

However this first idea would also include subsets of the actual word unless you compared length as well.

Another idea is to put them both into seperate arrays split on the comma character, then for each word in `a` array compare it with elements in the `b` array.

A possible C# solution could be like this:

```
public bool CompareWords(string a, string b)
{
    if (a.Length != b.Length)
        return false;
    var aArray = a.Split(',');
    var bArray = b.Split(',');
    var allExist = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < aArray.Length && allExist; i++)
    {
        allExist = bArray.Any(e => e == aArray[i]);
    }
    return allExist;
}
```

Comment: As well as checking length of strings.